# Linkedlist - Templates - Pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, linked-list

What is wrong this code? I'm getting an error at `runner = runner->next;`, after debugging, but I don't see what's wrong with it.

```
void Linkedlist<T>::add(T item)
{
    if (root == 0)
    {
        root = new Node<T>(item);
        cout << "Add, Root is empty \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Add, Root  is not empty \n";
        Node<T> * runner = root;
        while (runner != 0)
        {
            runner = runner->next;
        }
        runner = new Node<T>(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
Node<T> * runner = root;
while (runner->next != NULL)
{
    runner = runner->next;
}
runner->next = new Node<T>(item);
```

Your code only changes a local variable, and not the actual node. (Note that `runner->next` is an object in your actual list, while `runner` is just a local variable.)

Comment: Thanks, it works but I'm getting "Segmentation fault." when I debug it.

Comment: @AdegokeA Have you set any `root`s linked lists to `NULL`?

Comment: @AdegokeA: You still need the other branch that checks whether `root` is null, and make sure you initialize nodes correctly.